# How does node js handle a fileupload?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multer

How is node js (alone or with a framework like multer) handling a multipart post request?

I'm asking this, because I am a little bit confused about fileuploads in node.js.

It looks to me like node.js is receiving the whole file and then serves it via a file handle (e.g. to express/multer).

How can I check in node.js the filesize and abort the upload if the file is too big (**before** the whole file is transmitted !!!)?

Comment: Here's an example: https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable/blob/master/lib/incoming_form.js#L187

Answer (score -1):

Try [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) package then set maxFieldsSize config.